# AWS Batch job long STARTING time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I have an issue with long starting time for AWS Batch job. It's random, sometimes it takes second to transition from STARTING to RUNNING, but sometimes it takes more than 10 minutes. According to the documentation, in STARTING state container initiation operations are done, so I understand it can take some time to download and run container on newly created machine in compute environment, but it happens also on machines that were used just before and should have the container already prepared.
Is there any way I can optimise job's STARTING time?

Answer (score 2):

Duration of STARTING state [depends](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/job_states.html#:%7E:text=After%20the%20container%20image%20is%20pulled%20and%20the%20container%20is%20up%20and%20running%2C%20the%20job%20transitions%20to%20RUNNING.) on how fast an environment can pull and start a container.
You can speed things up if you use smaller Docker image (smaller the image, faster pulling and starting the container) and higher vCPU and RAM. All of these can be configured in Job Definition.

> it happens also on machines that were used just before and should have the container already prepared

You don't control how AWS manages an environment.